Missing ML activity while creating an IAM role for Sagemaker
I am trying to create an IAM role for Sagemaker for a project. While configuring this role, I need to choose the ML activity labeled as "Manage Endpoints." However, This ML activity does not appear as a choice while configuring the IAM role, even though it is listed in the ML activity reference.
Here is a screenshot of the reference

And here is a screenshot of what appears to me while creating the role:

I'm looking for a solution for this or maybe an alternative that gives me the required permissions for the role to function properly.
